# copy items from first list based on a value from second list in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have following two lists.

```
marks = [120, 80, 150, 130, 140, 130, 220]
student = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Zoe", "Joe", "Zoe", "Joe", "Zoe"]
```

I want to extract items from list 1 based on item 'Joe' from list 2 and then take a mean of extracted values. How can I do that using loop or list comprehension.

For example, extract `120`, `130`, and `130` from the `marks` list given the student `Joe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the two lists together and store the scores for the students in a dict. Then if you want to average it, just find the count of the student in the students list.

```
scores = {}
for mark, student in zip(marks, students):
    scores[student] = scores.get(student, 0) + mark

joe_average = scores['Joe'] / students.count('Joe')
```

If you just want the scores of a single student in a list, an easy comprehension would be

```
[mark for mark, student in zip(marks, students) if student == 'Joe']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that average as follows:

```
joes_marks = [m for m, s in zip(marks, student) if s == 'Joe']
sum(joes_marks) // len(joes_marks)
# 126
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Create a dict with empty list as default value.
d = defaultdict(list)

# Initialise the list.
student = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Zoe", "Joe", "Zoe", "Joe", "Zoe"]
marks = [120, 80, 150, 130, 140, 130, 220]

# Iterate list with enumerate.
for idx, e in enumerate(student):
    d[e].append(idx)

# Print out the occurrence of 'Joe'. 
res = d['Joe']  

sum_marks=0
for i in res :
    sum_marks += marks[i]

# Prin the output expected
print sum_marks/len(res)
```